# Page break in Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I need to generate a PDF with tables through a WEB API in **ASP.NET CORE**. I currently have a method that receives the HTML in a string and using the GetPDF method from **Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore**, I generate the PDF and then return it in bytes.

```
public IActionResult Html2Byte([FromBody] string html)
{
    var data = generatePdf.GetPDF(html);
    return Ok(data);
}
```

The problem is that I need to manually set a page break in the HTML between the tables to split them in different sections in the PDF.

I tried adding with the tag `<br>` and via CSS with the following classes using `@media print` and without it:

```
@media print {
    .keep-together-page {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    .break-before-page {
        page-break-before: always;
    }

    .break-after-page {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

However, no matter how I add the CSS, either by classes or directly in the style attribute, it still doesn't recognize the page break. The closest way I was able to reproduce was adding a height for the divs, but that it's not ideal due to the number of rows in the tables that may vary.

Is there something I can do to make it recognize the page break? Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Try placing a style attribute at the beginning of the HTML, for example -

```
<style type="text/css">
    .keep-together-page {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    .break-before-page {
        page-break-before: always;
    }

    .break-after-page {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I tried to do this already but it still doesn't work. It keeps ignoring the page break properties no matter how I add them

Comment: This actually now works with latest version. Just make sure to add this on the parent element (e.g. <div> wrapping entire 'page')